# What's the preferred method to optimize the maximum of the mean of an objective function?

Tags: optimization, binary-data

As in linear optimization, where you have an objective function and constraints, but the goal is to maximize the mean of this function, not the sum. (I am primarily interested in binary optimization of 0 or 1.)

Quick conceptual example: You have a number of stocks in a portfolio, with their expected returns in the objective function and then constraints limiting the selection. If you just optimize the maximum, even a .001% expected return will increase the total sum of returns, so this stock would be included. However, it lowers the average.

Comment: Just focus your optimization so as to maximize the average return of your stock portfolio.

Comment: I've removed the bounty from the question because the bounty remarks focused on implementation of such a model in software & debugging error messages, which is not an on-topic question on stats.SE.